# Mutation complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation

I include a 3rd party javascript, which in turn appends child elements to a DOM and the time taken to do this is variable, is there a way for me to find out when the Mutation is complete e.g. DOMNodeInserted is complete?

My code at the moment looks like

```
$("#searchgadget").bind("DOMNodeInserted",function(){
alert("added");}
```

As expected I get alerts for every 500+ elements that are being added to the "searchgadget", however, I am only interested when this finishes I just want to do some logic after the last DOMNodeInserted. Anyways to do that?

Comment: DOMNodeInserted is deptecated. Use MutaionObservers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code that's appending nodes is running synchronously, there won't be any delay between them. You can set a timeout each time a node is inserted. When the timeout completes, it's done with all the mutations.

```
insertTimeout = null;
$("#searchgadget").on("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
    clearTimeout(insertTimeout);
    insertTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        alert("added");
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Why did you choose 100ms? As it takes anywhere between 2 to 25 seconds to render the html, I am getting multiple alerts, it would be great if I just get one.

Comment: I didn't think the time mattered. As I wrote in the question, I assumed that all the modifications are being done synchronously, so the timeout won't run until it's all done. If my assumption is wrong, the answer won't work.

Comment: 25 seconds to update the page? Users really put up with this? Does it display any kind of progress indicator while it's doing this? You could wait for it to remove the indicator.

Comment: Or is that the problem -- you want to display an indicator, and remove it when all the modifications are done? If the application doesn't provide any indication of this, there's not really any way for the browser or your code to know.

Comment: Hi Barmar, yes there is a progress indicator (I am with you, with the horrible load time, it is what it is). I need to try and get the height of loaded HTML when it finishes, if that makes sense.

Comment: Use a `MutationObserver` to detect when the progress indicator is removed.